# R how to add text (with mtext?) when plotting with the multiplot function from cookbook-r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I use the `multiplot` function from [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/) to stack my numerous graphs of the form `graph<-ggplot(...)` with the line

```
png(filename = "qwerty.png", width = 1024, height = 1024, units = "px", 
    pointsize = 11, bg = "white",  res = 150)
multiplot(graph1,graph2,...., layout=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), nrow=8, 
          byrow=TRUE))
dev.off()
```

I want to add a few lines of text above the first graph, and the text could have complex editing with bold face for some letters for instance.

I tried to use, in placing it before and after `multiplot`

```
mtext(expression(paste("only ", bold("a"), " should be bold")), 1, 1)
```

but I get the error

```
Error in mtext(expression(paste("only ", bold("a"), " should be bold")),  : 
  plot.new has not been called yet`
```

Is it better to stack up another empty graph with my text ''as the graph'' ? If so, how can I do it ?

these data can be used to build the graphs for instance

```
p1 <- ggplot((subset(mtcars, gear==4)), aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) + 
      geom_point() +
      ggtitle("4 gears")
p2<-ggplot((subset(mtcars, gear==3)), aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle("3 gears")
multiplot(p1, p2, cols=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of multiplot you could use grid.arrange:

```
library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1,p2,ncol=2, nrow=1), main = "Here your title should be inserted",nrow=1)
```

If you want to adapt some text parameters, the following could help:

```
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1,p2,ncol=2, nrow=1), main = textGrob("Here your title should be inserted",gp=gpar(fontsize=16, font=2)))
```

To save the file:

```
png("example-plot.png")
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1,p2,ncol=2, nrow=1), main = textGrob("Here your title should be inserted",gp=gpar(fontsize=16, font=2)))
dev.off()
```

Comment: this does work, but I have trouble to save the stacked plots in a png file since, apparently, I must do `g <- arrangeGrob(p1, p2,ncol=2, nrow=1)` then `ggsave(file="whatever.png", g, width = 22, height = 22, units = "in", dpi = 120) +  dev.off()` and I lose the text added by `main = '''my text'`.

Comment: Not sure why your text disappears, I made some update in the answer where you should get the image including title.